# Background gradient degree to fit a desired width

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a simple background gradient that is of `45deg` incline:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/JLEeXM

```
.foo-bottom {
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, green 50%, yellow 50%, yellow);;
}
```

How do I set the gradient such a way so that the degree is always equal to 45 (or 315 if reverse) and that the top side of the fig I get is always 200px at any screen resolution:

[image]

I've also prepared a codepen that shows what I mean: https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/JLEeXM.

Comment: I find that just adding a picture that I made in photoshop is a lot easier and a lot less hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to split this into two gradient, the first one will cover the 200px and the second one will have the 45deg and to always have 45deg you have to make it always a **square**:

```css
.top {
  border-right: 200px solid green;
  height:30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bottom {
  --h:300px;
  height:var(--h);
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top left,green 50%,yellow 50%) calc(100% - 200px) 0/var(--h) var(--h) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(green,green)100% 0/200px 100% no-repeat;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If the height of the element will be dynamic simply specify a big values to the gradient size by keeping the square ratio:

```css
.top {
  border-right: 200px solid green;
  height:30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.bottom {
  height:50px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top left,green 50%,yellow 50%) calc(100% - 200px) 0/2000px 2000px  no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(green,green)100% 0/200px 100% no-repeat;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
---
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom" style="height:100px">
</div>
---
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom" style="height:600px">
</div>
```

**BONUS**

You can also combine both top and bottom element using one element:

```css
.box {
  border-top:30px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(to left,green 200px,yellow 200px) 1;
  height:200px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top left,green 50%,yellow 50%) calc(100% - 200px) 0/2000px 2000px  no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(green,green)100% 0/200px 100% no-repeat;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. However I will have to fix the height, right?

Comment: @sdvnksv i would say you are obliged since you have no centent ... but it you manage to use in a dymanic way, we my find a trick to make it work without fixed height, i will think about it ;)

Comment: The height is content dependendt, so I can't set a fixed height unfortunately.